# Retrieve domain name from email address

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, parsing, nltk

I am working on a huge email-address dataset in `Python` and need to retrieve the organization name.

For example, `email@organizationName.com` is easy to extract, but what about `email@info.organizationName.com` or even `email@organizationName.co.uk`?

I need a universal extractor that should be able to handle all different possibilities accordingly.

Comment: What have you tried? Any Python codes?

Answer (score 2):

If *organisationName* is always before .com or other ending - this may work -

```
        email_str.split('@')[1].split('.')[-2]
```

Comment: Thanks Rusheel, but as I have edited the post, what about orgname.co.uk etc.

Answer (score 2):

A regex won't work well here. In order to be able to reliably do this, you need to use a lib that has knowledge on what constitutes a valid suffix.

Otherwise, how would the extractor be able distinguish `email@info.organizationName.com` from `email@organizationName.co.uk`?

This can be done using [tldextract](https://pypi.org/project/tldextract/):

Example:

```
import tldextract

emails = ['email@organizationName.com', 
          'email@info.organizationName.com', 
          'email@organizationName.co.uk',
          'email@info.organizationName.co.uk',
         ]

for addr in emails:
    print(tldextract.extract(addr))
```

Output:

```
ExtractResult(subdomain='', domain='organizationName', suffix='com')
ExtractResult(subdomain='info', domain='organizationName', suffix='com')
ExtractResult(subdomain='', domain='organizationName', suffix='co.uk')
ExtractResult(subdomain='info', domain='organizationName', suffix='co.uk')
```

To access just the domain, use `tldextract.extract(addr).domain`.

Comment: Thanks buddemat, it has solved the problem.